# A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, expo

I am a new dev with around a year in web dev. I have built a few react apps now and also react-native apps. But these have all been new with the most recent react etc. I have no experience in taking over old applications The company that I work for has asked me to take over an old react native app that has not been worked on for almost 4 years. I have had a lot of issues getting the error list down. I have two errors that I just can't seem to fix. I am running the same Gradle, react-native, node, Java as well as the right SDK for android studio for this project. The app it's self was made for IOS only but I don't have a mac so since its react-native I decided I would try load it in android.

Ideally I would prefer not to just rewrite the whole application again so this is why I just aim to match the versions that the app was built in.

I am running the program in VSC with native cli and using android build 29.

I have been looking around for a little while now and every source I came across the app has this already included. Now I am out of ideas. Is there anyone who would be kind enough to help me.

Some additional information.
`node:14.17.0 <- I also tried this on 18 and 19 Java: 19 <- I have also tried 14 and 11 Gradle:6.2 <- I also tried updating this as well. React-Native: 0.64.3`

`gradle.build android  dependencies { classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")` 
I go into **cd android**  and then **./gradlew **

This is the error I get.

`FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\project\Desktop\Project React-Backup\node_modules\expo-application\android\build.gradle' line: 33
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-application'.
> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See [https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings`](https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings%60)

I need to get the application running with android emulator as I don't have a mac. This project was made for IOS just I am just working with what I have.

Things I have tried.

deleted and rebuild the IOS and Android folders.
downgraded react-native, JAVA, node and Gradle to match the versions on the app.

Comment: I thought I would update this, I was able to fix the issue. As stated above I was having these errors when running ./gradlew in the android folder. So how I fixed this issue and was able to build the project. It did later fail but this is due to the react version causing issues. I will fix that later its not related.

Comment: 1: in gradle-wrapper.properties, my distributionUrl was 6.3 so I changed it to.
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
(install gradle 6.5 and then run ./gradlew.

Comment: 2: In android/build.gradle I changed the dependencies {classpath} from 4.1.0 to 4.1.2
 dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2")
}

Comment: Next I closed the IDE and then reloaded. Use cd android to go into the folder and then use ./gradlew 
it will come up with a wall of text that goes on forever and then you should see build successful at the bottom in green.

I spent a while trying to fix this so hope it saves someone else the pain. See my original post for all the versions I am using. Also please note that I was having these issues as I was taking over a old broken app. 

Happy coding <3